# Magento 2 create object

Tags: magento2

I use third-party library in my module. I want to create a class object of this library using the factory class. But the problem is that constructor is this class takes 3 arguments string types.

```
namespace VendorName\ModuleName\Block\Adminhtml\System\Config\Form\Field;
class Shipping extends \Magento\Config\Block\System\Config\Form\Field
{
private $systemStore;
private $formFactory;
private $config;
private $shippingConfig;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\Data\FormFactory $formFactory,
    \Magento\Store\Model\System\Store $systemStore,
    \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $config,
    \Magento\Shipping\Model\Config $shippingConfig,
    \VendorName\ClassNameFactory $classNameFactory
) {
    $this->systemStore = $systemStore;
    $this->formFactory = $formFactory;
    $this->config = $config;
    $this->shippingConfig = $shippingConfig;
    $var = $classNameFactory->create([
        'param1' => 'value1',
        'param2' => 'value2',
        'param3' => 'value3'
    ]);
  }
}
```

And when I try create object like this I get error

> main.CRITICAL: Warning: Missing argument 2 for Vendor\Class::__construct(), called in vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php on line 93

Comment: can you please add full code of your file?

Comment: Yes of course. I think that I should declare these arguments in di.xml, 
but I do not know how to do it correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
namespace VendorName\ModuleName\MyClass;

class MyClassFactory
{
    public function create($param1, $param2, $param3)
    {
        return new \VendorName\ClassName($param1, $param2, $param3);
    }
}
```

I determined my factory class and use her

```
namespace VendorName\ModuleName\Block\Adminhtml\System\Config\Form\Field;
class Shipping extends \Magento\Config\Block\System\Config\Form\Field
{
private $systemStore;
private $formFactory;
private $config;
private $shippingConfig;

private $var;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\Data\FormFactory $formFactory,
    \Magento\Store\Model\System\Store $systemStore,
    \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $config,
    \Magento\Shipping\Model\Config $shippingConfig,
    \VendorName\ModuleName\MyClass $classNameFactory
) {
    $this->systemStore = $systemStore;
    $this->formFactory = $formFactory;
    $this->config = $config;
    $this->shippingConfig = $shippingConfig;
    $this->var = $classNameFactory->create([
        $param1,
        $param2,
        $param3
    ]);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code.

```
namespace VendorName\ModuleName\Block\Adminhtml\System\Config\Form\Field;
class Shipping extends \Magento\Config\Block\System\Config\Form\Field
{
private $systemStore;
private $formFactory;
private $config;
private $shippingConfig;
/**
 * @var NotEmpty
 */
private $var;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\Data\FormFactory $formFactory,
    \Magento\Store\Model\System\Store $systemStore,
    \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $config,
    \Magento\Shipping\Model\Config $shippingConfig,
    \VendorName\ClassNameFactory $classNameFactory
) {
    $this->systemStore = $systemStore;
    $this->formFactory = $formFactory;
    $this->config = $config;
    $this->shippingConfig = $shippingConfig;
    $this->var = $classNameFactory->create([
        'param1' => 'value1',
        'param2' => 'value2',
        'param3' => 'value3'
    ]);
  }
}
```

Comment: Does not work, the error is still present

Comment: because `\VendorName\ClassNameFactory` this path seems wrong.

Comment: Why? Class \VendorName\ClassName exist and \VendorName\ClassNameFactory automatically generated